# Find the general solution to this nonlinear ODE $y' + y = y^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution to this nonlinear ODE $y' + y = y^2$ and given the initial condition $y(0) = -\frac{1}{3}$ find also a particular solution.

What I have tried:

I have aimed to tackle this using the Bernoulli equation
$$y'+p(x)y = g(x)y^a.$$

Supplementing for $u(x) = y^{1-2}=y^{-1}$ after differentiating and substituting y' I get
$$u'=-y^{-2}(y^2-y)$$
$$\implies u'-y^{-1}=-1$$
$$\implies u' -u = -1$$

Then we take the integrating factor which is $e^{\int p(x)dx}$ which in this case we have $e^{-\int dx}=e^{-x}$ to get
$$e^{-x}u'-e^{-x}u=-e^{-x}$$ We can also put it into this form (though I forgot way so if someone could explain or direct a link that would be great!)

$\frac{d}{dx}(e^{-x}u)=-e^{-x}$
$\implies e^{-x}u=-\int e^{-x}dx+c$
$$u = 1+Ce^{x}$$

To find the particular solution from the initial condition I get $-\frac{1}{3}=1+Ce^0 \implies c = \frac{2}{3}$

Comment: Is your question about the product rule $\frac{d}{dx}(vu)=vu'+v'u$? // Note that you can get to the solution in a slightly faster way if you set $u=1-y^{-1}$, as then $u'=y^{-2}y'=u$. // Your last transformation should be to $u=1+Ce^{+x}$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I've just come across the product rule with linear combinations, is that something that could be used with tackling an ODE like this?

Comment: If you are doing differential equations, you should have long known derivatives and the rules of differentiation. While you may find the product rule in many different places, I do not think that what you mention is directly related to this topic.

Comment: Also note that $1+Ce^0=u(0)=\frac1{y(0)}=-3$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I understand now! Thanks for sharing it with me. Seems it is about the product rule. I had forgot what the initial condition was, so seeing your answer for $u(0)$ has helped cement it for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=y^2-y \implies \dfrac{dy}{y(y-1)}=dx$. Use partial fractions and integrate both sides.

Edit for further details:
$$(\dfrac{1}{y-1}-\dfrac{1}{y})dy=dx$$
$$\ln (y-1) -\ln y = x+ c$$
$$\ln \dfrac{y-1}{y}=x+c$$
$$\dfrac{y-1}{y}=\exp(x+c)$$
$$1-1/y=\exp(x+c)$$
$$y=\dfrac{1}{1-\exp(x+c)}$$

Comment: I get $\frac{y-1}{y}=Ce^x$

Comment: @me.limes I added further details.

Comment: Where might I have gone wrong with the application of the Bernoulli equation? The two answers look different.

Comment: @me.limes You power of the exponential is wrong. You should have $u(x)=1+C\exp(x)$.

Comment: In consideration of the initial value, your integration result should read $\ln(1-y)-\ln(-y)=x+c,$ otherwise you would have to use absolute values and then also allow the negative sign in $\frac{y-1}{y}=\pm\exp(x+c)$.